# Display an np.array more like they do in math

Tags: python, matrix

I know I can write a program to do this but I suspect there's a package somewhere that does it and a lot of searching has not yielded a result.I would like to be able to display an np.array more like math (not math notation, just the layout.) Like a kind of "pretty print" for np 2 dimensional arrays

```
np.array([1,2,3]) =>

1 2 3

np.array([[1,2,3]]) =>

 1
 2
 3

np.array([[1,2],[10,20], [100,200]]) =>

1 10 100
2 20 200
```

Again I know this is something that can be written but it must exist somewhere already?

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure how "they do in Math" besides Latex, but your probably looking for [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) which as link says is used to *"Pretty-print tabular data in Python"*. It supports Numpy arrays Pandas Dataframes and other input formats, and Latex, HTML and a bunch of other output formats. See link. Basic example:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
x = np.random.random((3,3))
print(tabulate(x))
```

Gives:

```
--------  --------  --------
0.665815  0.81955   0.509321
0.705763  0.928873  0.2974
0.116313  0.431765  0.543292
--------  --------  --------
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the function below does not work for high dimension input (i.e dim(X) >=3 ), it works well for dim(X) < 2.

```py
def pprint(X):
    
    if len(X.shape) == 1 :        
        return reduce(lambda acc, x : acc + " " + str(x) ,X, "")
        
    else:
        xs = zip(*X)
        
        return print("\n".join([pprint(np.array(x)) for x in xs]))
```